# If parseInt multiple item greater than 1, then do something

Tags: jquery, parseint

I have an output number of elements that are randomly generated and put into an isotope horizontal scroll, I wish to have the second row that will have a height 50% from the top have a different overlay colour.

I've got this far but it doesn't seem to work and I couldn't find anything similar on Stack Overflow.

```
$(function(){
    if ( parseInt($('.item').css('top'), 10) < 1 ) {        
        $(this).find('.overlay').css('background','#ff3366');
    }
    if ( parseInt($('.item').css('top'), 10) > 1 ) {
        $(this).find('.overlay').css('background','#0099ff');
    }  
});
```

JSFiddle example quickly put together to give an idea? http://jsfiddle.net/6tRwV/
If you could kindly assist me in making this work I will be very grateful.

Comment: what did you expect `this` to reference?

Comment: @KevinB the window object..... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to loop over all the `.item` elements and do pretty much the logic you had already.

```
$(function(){
    $('.item').each(function(){
        var $item = $(this);
        var top = parseInt($item.css('top'),10);
        if ( top < 1 ) {        
            $item.find('.overlay').css('background','#ff3366');
        }
        if ( top > 1 ) {
            $item.find('.overlay').css('background','#0099ff');
        }  
    })

});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tRwV/2/

as with all things jQuery, there is usually a shorter way:

```
$(function(){
    $('.overlay').css('background',function(){
        var top = parseInt($(this).parent().css('top'),10);
        return top<1 ? '#ff3366' : '#0099ff';
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tRwV/3/

Comment: Thank you! knew I wasn't far off.

Comment: It's a normal DRY thing to save the result of a calculation in a variable. +1 for that (though I'd like to see the intermediate version of the top code block with the `var top`...

Comment: Just for you @ErikE (Although I should have a `var $overlay = $item.find('.overlay');` in there too ;) The whole top example is a bit verbose. Id definately go with the second for simlicity.

Comment: Hi thanks for the additional short version, just pulling it all apart now :)

Comment: I think the `$item.find` twice is okay because it is only executed once. Also, I just noticed that if `top === 1`, nothing is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('div.item').each(function(){
    if (parseInt($(this).css('top'), 10) < 1) {
        $(this).find('.overlay').css('background', '#ff3366');
    }
    if (parseInt($(this).css('top'), 10) > 1) {
        $(this).find('.overlay').css('background', '#0099ff');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6tRwV/1/)**

Comment: Not solving the repetition of a calculation problem (repeating `parseInt`) is not recommendable.

Comment: Thank you also, great stuff!

Comment: @ErikE - please post a source that recommends that.

Comment: Dear @j08691: there is no need to post any source. It is pure logic and one of the most basic programming principles there is: running a function twice costs more CPU than storing the return value of that function and reusing it. If you really want to learn more about it, search online for "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself). You're actually repeating three functions: `parseInt`, `find` and `css`.

Comment: @ErikE - In an example such as this, you would notice absolutely zero difference.

Comment: @j08691 I'm sorry I mentioned CPU cost and performance at all, because the larger issue is the repeating yourself part. Code should be correct, clear, concise, and fast (in that order). Your code is correct, but less than clear: every time a developer looks at it, he has to examine the two `if` statements to see what they contain and if they in fact are the same (instead of you proving this by doing the expression only *once*) which wastes that developer's time and energy. Your code is also obviously not concise. Violating clarity and conciseness are *not recommendable*.